# Get Object of Calling Function

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that I can use `arguments.callee.caller.name` to get the name of the calling function, but how do I get the object on which the function was called on, i.e. what `this` means in there?

I want to know this as it's about a function I called `apply()` on to call it for another object.

Example: in some part of the code I have

```
function myFunc(param1, param2) {
  myComplexObject.someFunc();
}

myFunc.call(obj, param1, param2);
```

and now I want to write code in `myComplexObject.someFunc()` and somehow find `obj` from above:

```
function someFunc() {
  var callerFuncName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
  var callerFuncObj = ???
}
```

*I hope I'm making sense here...*

---

EDIT: This is a veeeeery much simplified situation of what I'm really in. Please understand that I don't have a fully-fledged debugger or something similar.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly can you pass `this` into `myComplexObject.someFunc` when you call it from `myFunc`?

Comment: You want to `callerFuncObj` be equal `myComplexObject`?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I think s/he wants it to be equal to `obj`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Using `arguments.callee` is considered a bad practice already in modern Javascript. You should reconsider your code so you don't have this kind of issues. Why do you need the calling object, after all? That's what the first argument of `call` and `apply` is for, so you can simply use `this`.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're trying to come up with a convoluted way to do something simple.

Comment: @MaxArt It's for debugging purposes. It won't be useful in production or something. We're trying to find a bug in our framework and we still wonder about the calling conditions.

Comment: @sjngm So why can't you give `someFunc` the signature `someFunc(obj)` and call it with `myComplexObject.someFunc(this)`?

Comment: @sjngm I guess you're dealing with some mobile or old browser, don't you? So you can't use a decent debugger and check the call stack?

Comment: @JamesAllardice I can't change anything in the calling code

Comment: @MaxArt Exactly, yes.

Comment: @JLRishe I can't change anything in the calling code

Comment: @sjngm What browser are you using, for the sake of curiosity?

Comment: @MaxArt It's called Ekioh

Comment: @sjngm Now that's some weird user agent you're dealing with. I've googled a bit and it seems it uses Webkit, so are you sure you can't emulate it in Chrome/Safari?  If not, I'm sorry you'll be back to the time web developers filled their code with `alert`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I get the object on which the caller function was called on, i.e. what this means in there?

You cannot. The `this` keyword is only accessible from the scope of your caller function, and there's no way to get introspection into that (unless you use a JS debugger with access to the JS engine).

So you would need to somehow pass `this` as an argument to your function, or find another way to make it available (e.g. as a global variable). This could be done either in the caller function (`setGlobal(this)`) or in the caller's caller (`setGlobal(obj)`) who also knows the object. If you cannot change that code, it's completely impossible.

The last resort would be some kind of side-channel attack, i.e. when you know the set of possible `this` values and know what properties the caller function accesses on it, you could set getters on these properties that will identify the object as "being accessed".

Comment: As there were no words in this question that it may work I guess you win.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was a bit confused - hopefully now I know what you are trying to do. What about this, it's not clean, but since you really are trying to do a little somersault here, it could work for you :

```
var f1temp;
function f1(){
 f1temp = this;
 f2();
}
function f2(){
 console.log(f1temp.num);
}
var a = { num:2 };
f1.call(a);
```

Will result in `2`. Therefore giving you access to the object as demonstrated.

**EDIT:** Ok, what about this:

```
function f1(){
 Function.prototype.temp = this;
 f2();
}
function f2(){
 console.log(Function.prototype.temp.num);
}
var a = { num:2 };
f1.call(a);
```

Comment: No, I don't have an intermediate object. That would be too easy ;) `f2()` doesn't know about `f1temp`, it would need to find it by doing some magic to come up with something that equals `f1temp`.

Comment: It's a global variable, F2 knows about f1temp. F1 just updates the value of that global variable everytime you use .call on it. You can add a global variable to any code you already have.

Comment: The conditions are that I don't know about `f1temp`. The framework is huge.

Comment: I told the other guys in the comments above that I can't change anything in the calling code. I forgot to mention that here, sorry.